# Cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Nontype' objects error despite all arguments being pure string

Tags: python, string, runtime-error

I'm writing this python program and I'm getting this really confusing error in random. Here's part of my script:

Part of code in `ai.py` (starting at line #133)

```
elif (config.var0 < config.var1):                   
    message = "SUCCESS_0021! var0 successfully adjusted."
    print message
    aux_func.write_log(message)
    config.var0 = float(config.var1)
    config.ask_trail = (1.0 + config.var2) * config.var3
```

The `write_log` function in `aux_func.py` file looks like this starting line #43

```
def write_log (message):
    log_file = open(current_dir + '//logs//' + date_stamp(), 'a+')
    temp_write = "\n " + time_stamp() + " : " + str(message)
    log_file.write(temp_write)
    log_file.close()
```

This works just fine and writes log file as expected most of the times. But, when I run this script for a while, then the console has this weird message that says:

```
Traceback <most recent call last):
  File "main1.py", line 102, in <module>
    func_flag = ai.decide()
  File "C:\project\ai.py", line 137, in task_decide
    aux_func.write_log(message)
  File "C:\project\aux_func.py", line 45, in write_log
    temp_write = "\n " + time_stamp() + " : " + str(message)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

The `ai.py` function is called from `main1.py` function.

I don't understand this error and I have banged my head against the wall to try and understand why I get this. The `message` is perfectly a string  and I don't see any 'NoneType' objects in my the code where the error is being shown.

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to give you the time_stamp() code, here you go:

```
def time_stamp():
    flag = 0        
    current_time = ''
    system_date_time = str (datetime.datetime.now())
    while (system_date_time == None):
        system_date_time = str (datetime.datetime.now())    
    for c in system_date_time:
        if (c == ' '):
            flag = 1
        if (c != '.'):
            if (flag == 1):
                current_time += c
            else:
                pass
        else:
            return current_time
```

Comment: You may want to post the definition of `time_stamp()` so I can tell you *why* it returns `None`.

Comment: Well, obviously not all the items are strings, otherwise you would not get that exception. So obviously one of the items being concatenated is a `None` value, and the only possibility is the result from calling `time_stamp()`.

Comment: Your error message is telling you that the statement "all arguments being pure string" is incorrect.  One of them is, in fact, `None`, not a str.

Comment: Hi guyz, (and @MartijnPieters) I have edited the question and added the definition of time_stamp() function. Can you please help me, I haven't been able to get rid of the error, thank you :)

Comment: What *is* that function supposed to do? Return the current time? There are easier ways to do so, not least by returning `datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')`.

Comment: Or rather, to include the seconds, `datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')`.

Comment: And although way overcomplicated, that function will not in fact return `None`.

Comment: Thanks for you help, sir. I'm new to python so my program may not be the most efficient. But, I tried some basic debugging and typecasting even the time_stamp like this str(time_stamp()), and despite the while loop, it IS returning None sometimes. I don't why that is happening though.

Answer (score 5):

It is the `time_stamp()` callable; it returns `None`.

Nothing else on that line could be `None` as they are either string literals, or the result of the `str()` function:

```
temp_write = "\n " + time_stamp() + " : " + str(message)
```

hence, the only remaining candidate is `time_stamp()`.

Comment: Seconded. Everything else involved in `temp_write` has to be a string. So `time_stamp()` must sometimes return `None`.

Comment: Martijn is right, I thought the order of the items printed in the TypeError where not necessarily in the right position but the error is in the concatenation of the "\n" and None